# C pointer frustration EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c, pointers

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with the following code? I'm getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`, Could not access memory.
Reason: `KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS`

I declare a global array of 7 pointers, each points to an int array, of different sizes.

```
int **pt_all_arrays[7];
```

In my function `A()`

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        int array_size = function_that_returns_array_size();
        int *myarray = (int *)malloc(array_size * sizeof (int));

        // DO WORK...    

        // Store the array in the big array
        *(pt_all_arrays[i]) = myarray;  <-----EXCEPTION
    }
```

The exception is thrown on the last line.
I'm running on Mac, `gcc -std=gnu99`

Comment: Apparently you didn't change the array elements from their initial `NULL`s. The way you use it, it looks like it should be `int *pt_all_arrays[7];`, and then just `pt_all_arrays[i] = myarray;`.

Comment: In deed, change to int *pt_all_arrays[7] solved the problem. I got confused by that fact that "a pointer to an int array actually points to the first element.", so I thought an array of pointers to array would be an array of pointers to pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would want to declare as

```
int *pt_all_arrays[7];
```

And then assign as

```
pt_all_arrays[i] = myarray;
```

With `int **pt_all_arrays[7];` you create array of pointer to pointer to int, which is not what you want.

And with `*(pt_all_arrays[i]) = myarray;` you are trying to change to address of array which is not valid.

Example

```
int array[7];
int *pi;
array = pi; //this is not valid.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But just to clarify what you said:    "int **pt_all_arrays[7]; you create array of pointer to pointer to int", but a pointer to an array is in fact a pointer pointing to it's first element, so with **pt[7], it's an array of pointer to pointer to int. Am I misunderstanding it?

Answer (score 2):

the definition of

```
int **pt_all_arrays[7];
```

should be

```
int *pt_all_arrays[7];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last line , you try to write to the memory location pointed by `pt_all_arrays[i]`. Since `pt_all_arrays[i]` hasn't been initialized, this might point anywhere. In your case, it points to an invalid memory address.

Answer (score 0):

```
int **pt_all_arrays[7];
```

This actaully declaires an array of 7 pointers to pointers to ints. (pointers to int arrays). So if you want to store arrays you just need:

```
int *pt_all_arrays[7];
```

When you access the array:

```
pt_all_arrays[i]
```

This is actually saying the same as:

```
*(pt_all_arrays + i)
```

So you don't want to add the additional `*` in to it, simply:

```
pt_all_arrays[i] = myarray;
```

Will do.